# Como ler um arquivo e inserir dados em c

Tags: c

Olá eu sou novo em C e tenho a seguinte duvida

tenho um programa que precisa salvar e ler dados de alunos

Exemplo de aluno abaixo:

```
 typedef struct academico{
     char nome[50];
     char cidade[30];
     char estado[20];
     char rga[12];
    }aluno;
```

eu consigo salvar tudo ok. obs. salvo toda a estrutura de um aluno, por linha.

na leitura eu uso um fgets detro de um while até o final do arquivo para ler todos os registros, dentro do while como abaixo

```
void lerAluno(){

FILE *ptArq;
char str[60];
ptArq = fopen("DadosAlunos", "r");

if(ptArq == NULL){
    printf("erro");
    return 0;
}
char linha[112];

while((fgets(linha, sizeof(linha),ptArq)) != NULL){

  //aqui eu usode uma função para ler a "string" até o ; e colocar dentro de uma variavel
 // porem após o primeiro ; eu não sei de nenhuma forma de separar os dados restantes da mesma forma sem usar um monte de variaveis e while
// é possivel resolver isso com ponteiros seria o ideal

}
```

Exemplo de como os dados estão dentro do arquivo:

augusto;treslagoas;ms;654321

jose;saopaulo;sp;123456

Comment: Creio que seria melhor você gravar e ler sua estrutura como um bloco de dados. Grave com fwrite e leia com fread.

Comment: Pesquise pela função strtok de <string.h>

Comment: Qual o problema ? Não le corretamente ? Dá erro ? Não abre o arquivo ? O que acontece ? Como foram guardados os valores no arquivo ? Qual o código que guardou os dados ?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer colocar o cadastro organizado, tente isso:

```
fprintf(ponteiroArquivo, "\n------------------------\n");
fprintf(ponteiroArquivo,"nome: %s\n",aluno.nome);
fprintf(ponteiroArquivo,"Cidade: %s\n",aluno.cidade);
fprintf(ponteiroArquivo,"Estado: %s\n",aluno.estado);
fprintf(ponteiroArquivo,"RGA: %s\n",aluno.rga);

fclose(ponteiroArquivo); //fecha o arquivo
```